# ExtJs 6 stores config on Ext.app.Controller not working

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I just noticed that stores config http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.2-classic/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-cfg-stores on Ext.app.Controller is not looking 
in the right path (happens the same with views config).

e.g

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Menu', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    stores: ['Menu']
...
});
```

this will look for

> http://localhost/myapp/app/controller/store/Menu.js?_dc=20160607211025

**notice the controller folder**

instead of

> http://localhost/myapp/app/store/Menu.js?_dc=20160607211025

At the beginning I thought this was a configuration issue specific to one of my projects but then got the same thing on a different project.

I am using ExtJs 6.02

I know I can use the full class name like MyApp.store.Menu but then the getter would be very ugly. (This is happening on a huge code base that I just upgraded so using the full class name would be my last resource).

**Has someone faced this issue ?**

Comment: Did you `require` the stores in your controller? This example suggests it's necessary: [Ext.app.Controller#cfg-stores](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.app.Controller.html#cfg-stores).

Comment: stores: ['Menu']
 should be all you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the reason (bear with me):

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.2-classic/source/Controller2.html#Ext-app-Controller

look at:

> onClassExtended -> Controller.resolveNamespace -> Ext.app.getNamespace

Those are the important ones, once the namespace is resolved there is a call to process dependencies:

```
Controller.processDependencies(proto, requires, namespace, 'store', data.stores);
```

I researched this and Ext.app.getNamespace is identical in ext 5 and 6

**so why is it in ExtJs 5**

`Ext.getNamespace("MyApp.controller.SomeController"); // returns MyApp`

**and on ExtJs 6**

`Ext.getNamespace("MyApp.controller.SomeController"); // returns MyApp.controller`

The reason is found by console.log `Ext.ClassManager.paths` there is now a new entry that corresponds to `MyApp.controller`

[image]

previously there was no key for MyApp.controller (ZHT.controller)

And what Ext.getNameSpace does is look for the 'deepest prefix' as you can see here http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.2-classic/source/Util.html#Ext-app-Util

[update]
**So one thing that can be done is to override the static method resolveNamespace like this:**

```
  statics: {
    resolveNamespace: function(cls, data) {
            var Controller = Ext.app.Controller,
                namespaceRe = cls.prototype.isProfile ? Controller.profileRegex : Controller.controllerRegex,
                className, namespace, match;
            /*
             * Namespace resolution is tricky business: we should know what namespace
             * this Controller descendant belongs to, or model/store/view dependency
             * resolution will be either ambiguous or plainly not possible. To avoid
             * guessing games we try to look for a forward hint ($namespace) that
             * Application class sets when its onClassExtended gets processed; if that
             * fails we try to deduce namespace from class name.
             *
             * Note that for Ext.app.Application, Controller.onClassExtended gets executed
             * *before* Application.onClassExtended so we have to delay namespace handling
             * until after Application.onClassExtended kicks in, hence it is done in this hook.
             */
            className = Ext.getClassName(cls);
            namespace = data.$namespace || data.namespace ||
                Ext.app.getNamespace(className) ||
                ((match = namespaceRe.exec(className)) && match[1]);

            //<debug>
            if (!namespace) {
                Ext.log.warn("Missing namespace for " + className + ", please define it "+
                    "in namespaces property of your Application class.");
            }
            //</debug>


            //This is the only change on this override.
            //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37731213/extjs-6-stores-config-on-ext-app-controller-not-working/37733261#37733261
            if(namespace && namespace.indexOf(".controller") > -1) {
                namespace = namespace.slice(0, namespace.indexOf(".controller"));
            }

            return namespace;
        }
  }
```

If you know of a better solution please let me know!

Comment: Not all instances have it, plus If I switch to using storeId's for referencing the stores I would lose the getters that are already being used, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issues and the way to solve this was to add all stores my application requires to the `stores` config in `app/Application.js`.

Comment: Even if I require the store on Application.js I still need to have keep the stores config in the controller so I can use the appropriate getter that is autognerated. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.2-classic/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-cfg-stores